# .NET MAUI Application Crashes After Working Fine

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, maui

My .NET MAUI app worked fine until a week ago, now that I opened it again it crashes. At first I had a 'circular dependancy' runtime error, but after that I started getting an System.ArgumentNullException error and now the app will start with a black screen then crash after a few seconds. There are no errors, it just crashes.

The previous System.ArgumentNullException looked like this:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')
  at at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TryInsert(String key, Object value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
  at at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Add(String key, Object value)
  at at Registrar.DynamicRegistrar.SetAssemblyRegistered(String assembly)
  at at ObjCRuntime.Class.Initialize(InitializationOptions* options)
  at at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.Initialize(InitializationOptions* options)
```

I tried restarting my computer, my testing environment and redownloading Visual Studio. I commented out

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(("/RecipeDetailsPage"), true, new Dictionary<string, object>         {             {"Recipe", recipe}         });
```

and any related code. As I thought the error could be about data/object pairs. When the exception was thrown, it would not give a source for any of my files.

Comment: The call stack (`at at Registrar.DynamicRegistrar.SetAssemblyRegistered(String assembly)`) suggests it's trying to load an assembly. Maybe you're missing a dependency?

Comment: 1) Is target Windows, or is it a mobile emulator? If emulator, Factory Reset. 2) To make sure isn’t corrupted, Delete solution’s hidden .vs folder, and .obj/.bin folders. 3) If still isn’t working, simplify until it works, then start adding code back in. Comment out any custom code that runs at startup, to try to find what is involved in crash. 4) Change page app starts on to a very simple page, and comment out any custom initialization code on that page.

Comment: Did you try to use the `try catch` to get the detailed error message which caused the crash?